# Objective C remove end of string after certain character

Tags: objective-c, string, character

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. I can do it in c but objective c is difficult.

I want to cut the end of a string after a certain character

so user@example.com will become user (cut at '@')

How do I do this?

Comment: There are actually many ways to do this. I'm surprised that you find it easier in c. It can be done as one-liners in objective-c in at least two different ways.

Comment: Well mastering is different from c strings, so I'm not entire sure of the interface workings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will give you the first chunk of text that comes before your special character.

```
NSString *separatorString = @"@";
NSString *myString = @"user@example.com";
NSString *myNewString = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:separatorString].firstObject;
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `substringToIndex:` and `rangeOfString:` methods, like this:

```
NSString *str = @"user@example.com";
NSRange pos = [str rangeOfString:@"@"];
if (pos.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *prefix = [str substringToIndex:pos.location];
}
```

Notes:

1. You need to check the location against `NSNotFound` to ensure that the position is valid.
2. `substringToIndex:` *excludes* the index itself, so the `@` character would not be included.